# Riemannian metric of a manifold defnied by a graph

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The manifold $S$ is seen as the image of the following embedding $\varphi:w\in W\mapsto\big(h(w),w\big)\in\mathbb{R}^{n_v
+n_w}$ where $W$ is a domain of $\mathbb{R}^{n_w}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^{n_w}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n_v}$ is smooth. I set $H(w)\in\mathcal{M}_{n_v,n_w}(\mathbb{R})$ the jacobian matrix of $h$ evaluated on $w$.

How can I prove that $T(w)=I_{n_w}+(H(w)^T)H(w)$ is the riemannian metric of $S$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compute the (Euclidean) inner products between the partial derivatives of $\varphi$. Using total derivatives one can do this more easily. Since the total derivative is given by $D\varphi(w) = (Dh(w), {\rm Id})$. So, given $v_1,v_2 \in \Bbb R^{n_w}$, we'll have $$\langle D\varphi(w)v_1, D\varphi(w)v_2\rangle_{\Bbb R^{n_w+n_v}} = \langle Dh(w)v_1,Dh(w)v_2\rangle_{\Bbb R^{n_v}} + \langle v_1,v_2\rangle_{\Bbb R^{n_w}}.$$This is the definition of the Euclidean inner product in $\Bbb R^{n_v+n_w}$: it turns out to be the direct sum of the inner products in $\Bbb R^{n_v}$ and $\Bbb R^{n_w}$. In matrix form, regarding $v_1$ and $v_2$ as column vectors, the right side is $$(Dh(w)v_1)^\top(Dh(w)v_2) + v_1^\top v_2 = v_1^\top(Dh(w)^\top Dh(w) + {\rm Id}_{n_w})v_2,$$as required. (In your notation, $H(w) = Dh(w)$)

Comment: I understand that computing this quantity gives the expected result. My problem is that I don't understand why we are computing this quantity, I've tried several things and it led me to prove that $(U, \varphi^{-1})$ is the unique local chart of $\varphi(W)$ (where $U$ is any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n_u+n_v}$ containing $\varphi(W)$)...

Comment: You're computing the pull-back of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\Bbb R^{n_v+n_w}}$ to $W$ under $\varphi$. By definition of pull-back this is exactly what we have computed.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers, but I think I don't understand. I'm trying to compute the Riemannian metric of $S=\varphi(W)$, not $W$. As you said, the pull back definition would lead me to a riemannian metric on $W$. Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: I have seen that I can compute the Riemannian metric by using the local charts. If $(U_x,\psi_x)$ is a local chart of $x\in\varphi(W)$, then the riemannian metric on $\varphi(W)$ induced by the euclidian metric of $\mathbb{R}^{n_v+n_w}$ is given by
$$g(x)_{i,j}=\langle d(\psi_x^{-1})\big(\psi(x)\big).e_i, d(\psi_x^{-1})\big(\psi(x)\big).e_j\rangle$$ for $i,j\in\{1,..., n_w\}$ (because $\varphi(W)$ is a $n_w$-dimensionnal submanifold)

So if I have the atlas of $\varphi(W)$ which consist only on $(\varphi(W),\varphi^{-1})$, it gives the expected Riemannian metric.

Comment: If you equip $W$ with the pull-back metric then $\varphi$ becomes an isometry. So it doesn't matter. This is the whole point of coordinate computations.

Comment: Actually my goal is to define such an integral:

$$\int_{\varphi(W)}f(x)dS(x)$$ where $dS(x)$ is the measure induced by the Riemannian metric on $\varphi(W)$ and I would like this object to be equal to:

$$\int_Wf\big(\varphi(w)\big)\sqrt{\det(T(w))}dw$$ where $dw$ is the Lebesgue measure

Comment: Then $\sqrt{\det T(w)}\,{\rm d}w$ should be the measure induced by the pull-back metric on $W$ under $\varphi$.

Comment: Which is, not surprisingly, $$\sqrt{\det({\rm Id} + H(w)^\top H(w))}\,{\rm d}w.$$